# WPF place arbitrary content around data-bound elements on a canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, data-binding

We have a (dynamic) list of things (several types, from the same base or interface) we want to place on a canvas. The things specify their positions. The things contain some graphics that must be displayed at that exact position on the canvas. For example, a map (as canvas background), and a list of cities that have a specific symbol. The size of the things can change at runtime.
But we also want to add some other content around these things, content that is not a fixed size. It must be positioned relative to the things, but without affecting their positions. For example, add a border to indicate selection. Or the name of the city, or its population count.

I have solved this using attached properties (a behavior), see my own answer below.

Does anyone know a better method?

Answer (score -1):

My way to solve this is to attach properties (that are data bound) to the key graphic element. The code behind those properties adjusts the `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` properties of the `ItemContainer`. Doing it from the other end (a style that binds the properties of the container) does not work, or at least I cannot think of an elegant way to reference a member of the data template in the container's style.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new List<Thing>
            {
                new Marker() { Position = new Point(10, 10) },
                new Marker() { Position = new Point(250, 50) },
                new Marker() { Position = new Point(50, 250) },
                new Marker() { Position = new Point(250, 250) },
                new Marker() { Position = new Point(150, 150) },
                new RoundThing() { Name = "R1", Radius = 10, Position = new Point(10, 10) },
                new RoundThing() { Name = "R2", Radius = 20, Position = new Point(250, 50) },
                new RoundThing() { Name = "R3", Radius = 30, Position = new Point(50, 250) },
                new RoundThing() { Name = "R4", Radius = 40, Position = new Point(250, 250) },
                new ComplexThing() { Name = "CX", Position = new Point(150, 150)},
            };
        }

        private void Canvas_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            mousePos.Text = Mouse.GetPosition(this).ToString();
        }
    }

    public abstract class Thing : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string property = null)
        {
#if DEBUG
            var pi = GetType().GetProperty(property);
            if (pi == null)
                throw new ArgumentException($"Property {property} not found on {this}");
#endif
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }


        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set
            {
                if (name == value)
                    return;
                name = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private string name;

        public Point Position
        {
            get => point;
            set
            {
                if (point == value)
                    return;
                point = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private Point point;


        public Point Offset
        {
            get => offset;
            set
            {
                if (offset == value)
                    return;
                offset = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        Point offset;



        public Geometry Geometry
        {
            get => geometry ??= CreateGeometry();
            set
            {
                if (geometry == value)
                    return;
                geometry = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private Geometry geometry;

        protected abstract Geometry CreateGeometry();
    }

    public class Marker : Thing
    {
        protected override Geometry CreateGeometry()
        {
            return g;
        }

        readonly static Geometry g;

        static Marker()
        {
            g = new EllipseGeometry();
            if (g.CanFreeze)
                g.Freeze();
        }
    }

    public class RoundThing : Thing
    {
        public double Radius
        {
            get => radius;
            set
            {
                if (radius == value)
                    return;
                radius = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
                Geometry = null;
            }
        }
        protected double radius;

        protected override Geometry CreateGeometry()
        {
            Offset = new Point(radius, radius);
            var g = new EllipseGeometry(new Point(radius, radius), radius, radius);
            if (g.CanFreeze)
                g.Freeze();
            return g;
        }
    }

    public class ComplexThing : Thing
    {
        protected override Geometry CreateGeometry()
        {
            Offset = new Point(25, 10);
            var grp = new GeometryGroup();
            grp.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry(new Point(10, 10), 10, 10));
            grp.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry(new Point(40, 10), 10, 10));
            grp.Children.Add(new EllipseGeometry(new Point(25, 30), 10, 10));
            if (grp.CanFreeze)
                grp.Freeze();
            return grp;
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Thing}">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Path Grid.Column="1" Data="{Binding Geometry}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"
                          local:PositionContainer.Position="{Binding Position}"
                          local:PositionContainer.Offset="{Binding Offset}"
                          local:PositionContainer.Container="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="some text"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="some rather long text"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RoundThing}">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                        <RowDefinition/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Path Grid.Column="1" Data="{Binding Geometry}" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2"
                          local:PositionContainer.Position="{Binding Position}"
                          local:PositionContainer.Offset="{Binding Offset}"
                          local:PositionContainer.Container="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContentPresenter}}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="some text"/>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="some rather long text"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Radius, StringFormat=f2}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Slider Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Radius}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Marker}">
            <Ellipse Width="6" Height="6" Margin="-3" Fill="DarkViolet" Canvas.Left="{Binding Position.X}" Canvas.Top="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseMove="Canvas_PreviewMouseMove"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter"> <!--so that the markers are placed at their positions-->
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ItemsControl>
        <TextBlock x:Name="mousePos" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp2
{
    public class PositionContainer
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PositionProperty =
             DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Position", typeof(Point), typeof(PositionContainer),
             new PropertyMetadata(default(Point), OnPositionChanged));

        public static void SetPosition(FrameworkElement element, Point value)
        {
            element.SetValue(PositionProperty, value);
        }

        public static Point GetPosition(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            return (Point)element.GetValue(PositionProperty);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty OffsetProperty =
             DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Offset", typeof(Point), typeof(PositionContainer),
             new PropertyMetadata(default(Point), OnOffsetChanged));

        public static void SetOffset(FrameworkElement element, Point value)
        {
            element.SetValue(OffsetProperty, value);
        }

        public static Point GetOffset(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            return (Point)element.GetValue(OffsetProperty);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContainerProperty =
             DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Container", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(PositionContainer),
             new PropertyMetadata(default(FrameworkElement), OnContainerChanged));

        public static void SetContainer(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement value)
        {
            element.SetValue(ContainerProperty, value);
        }

        public static FrameworkElement GetContainer(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            return (FrameworkElement)element.GetValue(ContainerProperty);
        }


        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
             DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Source", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(PositionContainer),
             new PropertyMetadata(default(FrameworkElement)));

        public static void SetSource(FrameworkElement element, FrameworkElement value)
        {
            element.SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
        }

        public static FrameworkElement GetSource(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            return (FrameworkElement)element.GetValue(SourceProperty);
        }


        static void OnPositionChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Apply((FrameworkElement)d);
        }

        static void OnOffsetChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Apply((FrameworkElement)d);
        }

        static void OnContainerChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var source = (FrameworkElement)d;
            if (e.OldValue is FrameworkElement oldContainer)
            {
                oldContainer.SizeChanged -= OnSizeChanged;
                SetSource(oldContainer, null);
            }
            if (e.NewValue is FrameworkElement newContainer)
            {
                newContainer.SizeChanged += OnSizeChanged;
                SetSource(newContainer, source);
                Apply(source);
            }
        }

        static void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Apply(GetSource((FrameworkElement)sender));
        }

        static void Apply(FrameworkElement element)
        {
            var container = GetContainer(element);
            if (container == null)
                return;

            var offset = GetOffset(element);
            if (container != element)
                offset = element.TranslatePoint(offset, container);
            var position = GetPosition(element);
            position -= (Vector)offset;

            container.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, position.X);
            container.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, position.Y);
        }
    }
}
```